# Multiple errors when compiling a RPG ILE program

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm trying to copy code of a RPG ILE program same as in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2bS3kRpC8Q&list=PL34QvIMpkj1lOoWJuyx2BHbXwYC7llIpe (Minute 34:18)

This is the code I wrote:

```
H                                                                       
 * Global variables (accessible to all sub procedures local to this pro 
D Sum             S              4P 0                                   
 * SubProcedure prototype OK                                            
DSubProcedure1    PR             4P 0                                   
D                                4P 0 VALUE                             
D                                4P 0 VALUE                             
 /Free                                                                  
      Sum = 0; // Initialize global variable                            
      Sum = SubProcedure1(5:10);                                        
      DSPLY Sum;                                                        
      *INLR = *ON;                                                      
 /End-Free                                                              
 *                                                                      
 * SubProcedure Begin                                                   
PSubProcedure1    B                                                     
 * SubProcedure Input                                      
DSubProcedure1    PI             4P 0                      
D num1                           4P 0 VALUE                
D num2                           4P 0 VALUE                
 * local variable to this subprocedure only (scope limited)
D Sum             S              4P 0                      
 /Free                                                     
      Sum = num1 + num2;                                    
      Return Sum;                                           
 /End-Free
```

When compile, I get this message from the spooled file:

```
5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1      
 Command  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   CRTBNDRPG                               
   Issued by  . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY85                                
 Program  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   ILEPGM1                                 
   Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY851                               
 Text 'description' . . . . . . . :   *SRCMBRTXT                              
 Source Member  . . . . . . . . . :   ILEPGM1                                 
 Source File  . . . . . . . . . . :   QRPGLESRC                               
   Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     REUY851                               
   CCSID  . . . . . . . . . . . . :     273                                   
 Text 'description' . . . . . . . :   RPG ILE PROGRAM WITH SUBPROCEDURE       
 Last Change  . . . . . . . . . . :   04/17/23  05:03:29                      
 Generation severity level  . . . :   10                                      
 Default activation group . . . . :   *YES                                    
 Compiler options . . . . . . . . :   *XREF      *GEN       *NOSECLVL  *SHOWC 
                                      *EXPDDS    *EXT       *NOSHOWSKP *NOSRC 
                                      *DEBUGIO   *UNREF     *NOEVENTF     
 Debugging views  . . . . . . . . :   *STMT                               
 Debug encryption key . . . . . . :   *NONE                               
 Output . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *PRINT                              
 Optimization level . . . . . . . :   *NONE                               
 Source listing indentation . . . :   *NONE                               
 Type conversion options  . . . . :   *NONE                               
 Sort sequence  . . . . . . . . . :   *HEX                                
 Language identifier  . . . . . . :   *JOBRUN                             
 Replace program  . . . . . . . . :   *NO                                 
 User profile . . . . . . . . . . :   *USER                               
 Authority  . . . . . . . . . . . :   *LIBCRTAUT                          
 Truncate numeric . . . . . . . . :   *YES                                
 Fix numeric  . . . . . . . . . . :   *NONE                               
 Target release . . . . . . . . . :   *CURRENT                            
 Allow null values  . . . . . . . :   *NO                                 
  Define condition names . . . . . :   *NONE                                  
  Enable performance collection  . :   *PEP                                   
  Profiling data . . . . . . . . . :   *NOCOL                                 
  Licensed Internal Code options . :                                          
  Generate program interface . . . :   *NO                                    
  Include directory  . . . . . . . :                                          
  Preprocessor options . . . . . . :   *NONE                                  
  REQUIRE PROTOTYPE FOR EXPORT . . :   *NO                                    
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-  
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1     
Line   <---------------------- Source Specifications -------------------------
Number ....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+.
                          S o u r c e   L i s t i n g                         
     1 H                                                                      
     2  * Global variables (accessible to all sub procedures local to this pro
     3 D Sum             S              4P 0                                  
     4  * SubProcedure prototype OK                                           
     5 DSubProcedure1    PR             4P 0                                  
======> aaaaaaaaaaaaa                                                         
*RNF3788 30 a      000500  DFTACTGRP(*NO) must be specified for a prototype th
                           not have the EXTPGM keyword.                       
     6 D                                4P 0 VALUE                            
     7 D                                4P 0 VALUE                            
     8  /Free                                                                 
     9       Sum = 0; // Initialize global variable                           
    10       Sum = SubProcedure1(5:10);                                       
    11       DSPLY Sum;                                                       
    12       *INLR = *ON;                                                     
    13  /End-Free                                                             
    14  *                                                                     
    15  * SubProcedure Begin                                                  
    16 PSubProcedure1    B                                                    
    17  * SubProcedure Input                                                  
    18 DSubProcedure1    PI             4P 0                                  
    19 D num1                           4P 0 VALUE                            
    20 D num2                           4P 0 VALUE                            
    21  * local variable to this subprocedure only (scope limited)            
    22 D Sum             S              4P 0                                  
    23  /Free                                                                 
    24      Sum = num1 + num2;                                                
    25      Return Sum;                                                       
    26  /End-Free                                                             
*RNF1502 20     16 001600  The Procedure specification ending the previous pro
                           is missing.                                        
       * * * * *   E N D   O F   S O U R C E   * * * * *                      
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-  
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1     
          A d d i t i o n a l   D i a g n o s t i c   M e s s a g e s         
 Msg id  Sv Number Seq     Message text                                       
*RNF7503 30     10 001000  Expression contains an operand that is not defined.
 * * * * *   E N D   O F   A D D I T I O N A L   D I A G N O S T I C   M E S S
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-  
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1     
                          C r o s s   R e f e r e n c e                       
      File and Record References:                                             
         File              Device             References (D=Defined)          
           Record                                                             
         No references in the source.                                         
      Global Field References:                                                
         Field             Attributes         References (D=Defined M=Modified
         *INLR             N(1)                   12M                         
         SUBPROCEDURE1     P(4,0)                  5D     10      16      18  
                           PROTOTYPE                                          
         SUM               P(4,0)                  3D      9M     10M     11  
      Field References for subprocedure SUBPROCEDURE1                          
         Field             Attributes         References (D=Defined M=Modified 
         NUM1              P(4,0)                 19D     24                   
         NUM2              P(4,0)                 20D     24                   
         SUM               P(4,0)                 22D     24M     25           
      Indicator References:                                                    
         Indicator                            References (D=Defined M=Modified 
         LR                                       12M                          
       * * * * *   E N D   O F   C R O S S   R E F E R E N C E   * * * * *     
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-   
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1      
                      E x t e r n a l   R e f e r e n c e s                    
      Statically bound procedures:                                             
         Procedure                            References                       
         No references in the source.                                          
      Imported fields:                                                         
         Field             Attributes         Defined                         
         No references in the source.                                         
      Exported fields:                                                        
         Field             Attributes         Defined                         
         No references in the source.                                         
   * * * * *   E N D   O F   E X T E R N A L   R E F E R E N C E S   * * * * *
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-  
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1     
                          M e s s a g e   S u m m a r y                       
 Msg id  Sv Number Message text                                               
*RNF1502 20      1 The Procedure specification ending the previous procedure i
                   missing.                                                   
*RNF3788 30      1 DFTACTGRP(*NO) must be specified for a prototype that does 
                   not have the EXTPGM keyword.                               
*RNF7503 30      1 Expression contains an operand that is not defined.        
       * * * * *   E N D   O F   M E S S A G E   S U M M A R Y   * * * * *    
                                                   -=* http://pub400.com *=-   
 5770WDS V7R5M0  220415 RN        IBM ILE RPG             REUY851/ILEPGM1      
                            F i n a l   S u m m a r y                          
  Message Totals:                                                              
    Information  (00) . . . . . . . :        0                                 
    Warning      (10) . . . . . . . :        0                                 
    Error        (20) . . . . . . . :        1                                 
    Severe Error (30+)  . . . . . . :        2                                 
    ---------------------------------  -------                                 
    Total . . . . . . . . . . . . . :        3                                 
  Source Totals:                                                               
    Records . . . . . . . . . . . . :       26                                 
    Specifications  . . . . . . . . :       15                                 
    Data records  . . . . . . . . . :        0                                 
    Comments  . . . . . . . . . . . :        6                                 
         * * * * *   E N D   O F   F I N A L   S U M M A R Y   * * * * *
```

Maybe is some about configuration for compiling, I don't know, but when I compile source member with 14 and press F4 and change activation group to NO, It doesn't save changes.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile with CRTBNDRPG and you have procedures in the body of the module, you must have DFTACTGRP set to *NO to compile.

There is multiple way to do it, you can set the value using the command like you did or

```
 H dftactgrp(*no)
```

You also can condition it's presence in the source depending on the command you use

```
  /IF DEFINED(*CRTBNDRPG)
 H dftactgrp(*no)
  /ENDIF
```

The reason why it didn't work for you is that there was another error behing this one : is a missing line in the source that closes the procedure definition

```
 PSubProcedure1    E
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are using IBM i v7.5, and programming like you are stuck at v6.1 so there are several things you want to do here. First, stop using fixed format code all together. You no longer need to code H, D, and P specs in fixed format. Second you no longer need `/Free` and `/End-Free`. Just put `**free` as the first line of your program. But, if you insist on a mix of fixed format and free format code, just omit the `**free` and code the lines. You still do not need `/Free` or `/End-Free`, the compiler can tell the difference and they just clutter the code.

So it should look like this:

```
**free
ctl-opt DatFmt(*iso) TimFmt(*iso)
        DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*New)
        Option(*NoDebugIo: *SrcStmt: *NoUnref)
        Main(main);  

// Global variables (accessible to all sub procedures local to this pro 
dcl-s Sum Packed(4:0) inz(0);
                 
// Main procedure
dcl-proc main;                       
   Sum = SubProcedure1(5:10);                                        
   dsply Sum;                                                        
   // *INLR = *ON; This is unnecessary
end-proc;                                                              
                                                           
// SubProcedure Begin                                                   
dcl-proc SubProcedure1;                                     
   dcl-pi *n Packed(4:0);
      num1 Packed(4:0) value;
      num2 Packed(4:0) value;
   end-pi;
 
   return num1 + num2; 
end-proc;
```

So lets look at this line by line:

```
**free
```

This tells the compiler that the program is entirely free format, fixed format lines are not allowed, and that the cycle is not going to be involved. So, things that use or control the cycle like *INLR have no meaning. There is also no columnar importance at all for the code. Your code go from column 1 all the way to the end of the record line. There are no sequence or comment columns, and the record length can be greater than 80.

```
ctl-opt DatFmt(*iso) TimFmt(*iso)
        DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*New)
        Option(*NoDebugIo: *SrcStmt: *NoUnref)
        Main(main);
```

This is what used to be the H spec. You can use this for every program, but modules will want `NoMain` instead of `Main()`. In addition you will want to use `ActGrp(*Caller)` for modules. I usually use the program name as the main procedure name. The reason for that is that if you are copying in program prototypes, every program needs a different prototype name. And you really want to use prototypes in a separate copy source to provide parameter checking in calling programs as Barbara said in the comments.

```
dcl-s Sum Packed(4:0) inz(0);
```

This is the D spec for the global variable, the variable is defined and initialized all in one step. There is no longer a need for a prototype for procedures defined in the program source, so that is dropped.

```
dcl-proc main;                       
   Sum = SubProcedure1(5:10);                                        
   dsply Sum; 
end-proc;
```

The main procedure source is now enclosed is a procedure definition. I named it main here, but I usually name it after my program. Notice it starts with a `dcl-proc` and ends with `end-proc`.

```
dcl-proc SubProcedure1;                                     
   dcl-pi *n Packed(4:0);
      num1 Packed(4:0) value;
      num2 Packed(4:0) value;
   end-pi;
 
   return num1 + num2; 
end-proc;
```

Finally, the sub-procedure definition starts with `dcl-proc` and ends with `end-proc` just like the main procedure. These are the P specs in fixed format, one with a B and the other with an E. You don't even need the intermediate declaration of sum  in this case because the expression is simple enough to just return the result.

---

Edit: The reported bug wasn't a bug, but there were a couple typos that occurred as a result of me coding recently in Java (, instead of : separating parameters), fixed now with a compile just to prove it works.
[image: Compiled in RDi]

Comment: If you use the name "main" for every main procedure name, you have to use a different name for the prototype if you want to call it from a different RPG module. But if you copy that prototype into the module with the procedure called "main", the compiler looks for a prototype called "main", so you lose the parameter-checking that the prototype normally provides to ensure that all the callers and the procedure itself have the same idea about the return value and parameters.

Comment: The main procedure doesn't need a return statement. It's a "linear-main", so it only goes through the calculations once, and returns when it gets to the end. You only need a return statement for a "cycle-main" procedure, where you would have to set on *INLR or have a return statement to get the program to stop cycling through the calculations over and over.

Comment: Thanks Barbara, that is exactly why I don't use "main" for the main procedure name. That bit of information had been lost to my mind over the years.

Comment: Also thanks for the reminder on the return. I was getting confused with the "cannot determine how program will end" error I get sometimes because some of the old programs I work with are not linear main. Post edited.

Comment: Using this example the editor returns: "Control-Level entry is not valid; defaults to previous control level. " at line 0002 (ctl-opt DatFmt(*iso) TimFmt(*iso))

Comment: @reymagnus This should start in column 1 not column 7. And `**free` must be on the first line of the source.